# How to inverse transform sample with a PDF that maps $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$?

Tags: probability-distributions, inverse, sampling

Given a PDF:
$$
p(x,y) = \frac{\pi^2\sin(\pi x)\sin(\pi y)}{4}.
$$
I obtain a CDF using double integral:
$$
P(x,y) = \frac{(1-\cos(\pi x))(1-\cos(\pi y))}{4}.
$$
And then I'm stuck, normally one would proceed to invert the CDF, but I can't really invert a multivariate function, can I?

Comment: That is correct, which is why cdf can't be inverted for a multivariate function.  Fortunately, since your distributions has X and Y independent, you can simply calculate the cdf's of the marginals and invert them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your distribution has $X$ and $Y$ independent of each other, you can calculate the cdf's of the marginals and invert them separately.  The marginal for $x$ is
$$p(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}sin(\pi x)$$
with cdf
$$P(x)=\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} cos(\pi x)$$ which inverted gives
$$x = \frac{1}{\pi}cos^{-1} (1 - 2P(x))$$